# How can I peruse the tweets by ELU?

Tags: discussion

In my Tweeter I searched for

- Stack Exchange English Language and Usage

and received results only on 4 tweets!!!!
and then followed sacramental

> Older Tweet results for Stack Exchange English Language and Usage are unavailable.

So, how can I peruse through tweets by Stack Exchange English Language and Usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks OK to me

http://twitter.com/#!/stackenglish

Comment: wow, thanks. Twitter is so jammed that it does not even show me complete list of users I follow there